# How to get an interface from an object created from a TClass?

Tags: delphi, interface

I need that some of my form classes implement the same function.

(I've discarded the idea of adding this function to a common anchestor form because I don't want to add a function which would be useless on most of my forms.)

So... I thought about using interfaces.

```
IMyInterface = interface
  procedure ShowHello();
end;

var  
  MyForm : TMyForm;
  MyInterface : IMyInterface;
begin
  MyForm := TMyForm.Create(Self);
  MyInterface := MyForm;
  //...
end;
```

In simple cases like this, it works without errors, but my application uses dynamic packages and I'm using "GetClass" function in order to obtain form classes. 
I tried as follows:

```
var
  MyForm : TForm;
  MyInterface : IMyInterface;
begin
  MyForm := TForm(GetClass('TMyForm').Create());
  MyInterface := MyForm;
end;
```

It causes "Incompatible types: 'IMyInterface' and 'TForm'" error.
Is there a way to achieve my goal using interfaces or it would be better to try other ways?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`Supports`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.SysUtils.Supports) function to check whether an interface is implemented or not.

**Sample**:

```
var
  MyForm : TForm;
  MyInterface : IMyInterface;
begin
  MyForm := TFormClass(GetClass('TMyForm')).Create(...);

  if Supports(MyForm, IMyInterface, MyInterface) then
  begin
    MyInterface.ShowHello;
  end;
end;
```

You need to declare GUIDs for your interfaces. Otherwise `Supports` doesn't work. So the interface declaration should look like this:

```
IMyInterface = interface
  ['{052E7D55-B633-4256-9084-37D797B01BB4}']
  procedure ShowHello();
end;
```

Comment: I did as suggested but Supports results false. TMyForm class is declared as "TMyForm = class(TForm, IMyInterface)". Is there something missing?

Comment: The interface type needs a unique GUID in its declaration. Does it have a GUID?

Comment: Yes, I've pressed Ctrl + Shift + G in order to get one and I've added it to IMyInterface declaration.

Comment: Sorry! There was a little bit confusion in my test project, now "Supports" results True and ShowHello function is correctly executed! Thanks alot for your answer!